# Ubuntu boots quickly but is very slow loading X windows

Tags: 12.04, unity, boot

I've heard a lot about fast booting in Ubuntu 12.04. Unfortunately my experience is a bit different. My ubuntu boots like this:

- from grub to noticeable mouse cursor ~30s + ~10s for desktop picture
- from desktop picture to unity panel ~35s
- then another ~45s for e.g. nautilus to be loaded

All in all, I am not able to use my computer in less than two minutes, which is quite a lot, isn't it?

Note that `dmesg log`'s last two rows are:

```
[   23.169677] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[   34.064021] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Look at the time - 34s. What am I waiting for after?

Good to know: I am using the default nouveau driver instead of nvidia's. On Ubuntu 11.10 the boot took exactly the same time (I've made a new install to Ubuntu 12.04 though).

I know this question may be a bit too concrete, I would appreciate any information how to debug this as well, since I have no idea what's going on after the mentioned 34th second.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken to disabling networking before I shut down/suspend.

Desktop environment now loads in less than 10 seconds after login, then I enable networking, which is almost always instantaneous.

Prior to doing this I had the same issues as you, where from login to a usable desktop was taking almost a minute under 12.04 whether I used Ubuntu, Gnome or KDE.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how to do that? Do you mean uninstall the network manager? I've tried `ifconfig wlan0 down`, but that restores back online automatically in a second. thx